# Consecutive pairs from list in haskell

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

How can I get a list of consecutive pairs (tuples) from a list without recursion ?

For example : `[1, 2, 3, 4]` would be `[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]`

Comment: also, `(\xs-> [(x,y) | (x:y:_)<- tails xs])`. [`tails`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:tails) is defined with recursion, but then so is `zip`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`\xs -> zip xs $ tail xs` or `zip <*> tail`.

Comment: The latter would better be written `zip<*>tail`. I'm actually not a big fan of these function-functor hacks, but I have to admit that this here is pretty nice.

Comment: It doesn't save any brackets here so whatevz but sure.

Comment: `ap` is somewhat obsolete now that `Applicative` is a superclass of `Monad` (at least in GHC, and assuming it is adopted by the Haskell 2014 standard).

Comment: If they're gonna make return an alias of pure, then ap will be a prefix alias of <*>, right?

Comment: For other noobs like me, the relevant instance of Applicative being used is the instance for functions of a common first argument type, `((->) r)`, for which you have `<*> f g x = f x (g x)`, which apparently is also called the S combinator.

Comment: Oddly, while the current implementation does define `return = pure`, it still provides an explicit definition of `ap` due to the amount of existing code that just defines `(<*>) = ap`. I guess `pure` was easy enough to implement directly that fewer people would define it as `return`?

Comment: The fact that this works for empty lists is a bit subtle for my taste.