# Consecutive n-tuples from a list in haskell

Tags: haskell

Is there an easy-ish / general way to get consecutive n-tuples? For example:

```
f3 [1,2,3,4,5,6] = [(1,2,3),(2,3,4),(3,4,5),(4,5,6)]
f4 [1,2,3,4,5,6] = [(1,2,3,4),(2,3,4,5),(3,4,5,6)]
```

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36670539/consecutive-pairs-from-list-in-haskell) however it only covers pairs `(x,y)`.

Comment: You'd have to implement `f3` and `f4` independently, because their return types have nothing in common (a 3-tuple is not related to a 4-tuple at all in the type system). To make the implementation easy, you might consider using a ZipList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @amalloy points out in the comments, there's no straightforward way to define this operation generally across different tuple sizes, but if you're just looking for a general *pattern* for writing a set of such functions, there are a few possibilities.

The simplest, though it looks a little physically repulsive, is just to write a simple recursive pattern match that spits out a tuple and then recurses on the tail of the argument, stopping as soon as the list becomes too short:

```
f3 :: [a] -> [(a,a,a)]
f3 (x1:nxt@(x2:x3:_)) = (x1,x2,x3):f3 nxt
f3 _ = []

f4 :: [a] -> [(a,a,a,a)]
f4 (x1:nxt@(x2:x3:x4:_)) = (x1,x2,x3,x4):f4 nxt
f4 _ = []
```

While you could generalize the solution you linked to for pairs by writing:

```
f3' = zip3 <*> tail <*> tail.tail
f4' = zip4 <*> tail <*> tail.tail <*> tail.tail.tail
```

this is too clever by half and also not a particularly efficient solution, as every argument repeats the tail operations of the previous argument when the results could be reused.

An alternative and probably reasonably approach is:

```
f3'' str = let l1:l2:l3:_ = tails str in zip3 l1 l2 l3
f4'' str = let l1:l2:l3:l4:_ = tails str in zip4 l1 l2 l3 l4
```

though it relies on having the right `zipk` available.  While `zip3` is defined in `Prelude` and `zip4` through `zip7` are defined in `Data.List`, if you need `zip8` or more, you need to define it yourself.